# How can I find the Microsoft Edge version on Windows 10 in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I've searched through the SOFTWARE\Classes and SOFTWARE\Microsoft subkeys, but couldn't find anything related to "spartan" or "edge". Given that Edge is still very new, there really isn't much information about this yet.

As an example, this is how I gather the information about the Internet Explorer Version via the registry on a remote machine:

```
$ieVersion=[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $args[0]).OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer').GetValue('SvcVersion')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Get-AppxPackage` command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach Version
```

The package name is valid on build 10240 but if you are on an earlier build, it might be different.  If the above doesn't find the package try `-Name *Edge*` or `-Name *Spartan*`.

Comment: This does answer the question, but I am currently dealing with problem where I need to execute this command from a remote machine. Since I can't run this command due to a permissions error, is there a different way to accomplish this that you know of? Preferably via the registry or by examining the version of a file somewhere?

Comment: What permissions error? I was able to execute the above command using PowerShell remoting - worked fine.

Comment: My current situation does not allow for PowerShell remoting due to security issues.

Answer (score 3):

You may see multiple versions of Edge installed via Appx-Packages. I would recommend this approach:

```
$EdgeExe = Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\msedge.exe' "(default)"
$version = (Get-Item $EdgeExe).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped me finding an answer. The Get-AppxPackage commands above returned nothing on my system (Windows Server 2016, Powershell 5.1.1). My solution (because i might use different edge installations): (Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion

Answer (score 1):

```
$productPath = $Env:WinDir + "\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_*\MicrosoftEdge.exe" 
If(Test-Path $productPath) { 
    $productProperty = Get-ItemProperty -Path $productPath 
    Write-Host $productProperty.VersionInfo.ProductVersion 
} 
Else { 
    Write-Host "Not find Microsoft Edge." 
}
```

Source [How to determine the version of Microsoft Edge browser by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com//How-to-determine-the-28b42ea7)

Answer (score 1):

For Edge on Chromium above 44 version

powershell:

```sh
Get-AppxPackage -Name *MicrosoftEdge.* | Foreach Version
```

cmd:

```sh
powershell "Get-AppxPackage -Name *MicrosoftEdge.* | Foreach Version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested using two commands back to back.  I ran from an elevated PowerShell session New-PSSession -ComputerName "The remote PC I was testing this on." and then once the connection was made I ran the Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicsrosoftEdge and it pulled down the information, but I think it was more build information.  You can also filter it down to version using the Pipe character.  The full command looked like this.
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | select-object Version

I found this forum and others that lead me to some of the other switches and parameters I did not know about.

[How can I find the Microsoft Edge version on Windows 10 in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612102/how-can-i-find-the-microsoft-edge-version-on-windows-10-in-powershell)

I was trying to find an alternate way of remotely finding out what browser version it was. Trying to verify if it is updating regularly.  I am still learning.  I hope this helps.  I found another article that shows me exactly what I am looking for differently without powershell.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/161325-how-find-version-microsoft-edge-chromium-installed.html#option2